# how i can pass multiline String to maven in jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multiline

I am not much familiar with the Groovy script. I have a multiline string in one of my sample Jenkins Pipeline as below

[image: jenkins Image]

I need to get Input from User and pass this to maven in environment variable. I am using this in my maven command

```
test -Dtest="TestclassName" -DDATA=${DATA}
```

My problem is that when i am echoing the value of ${DATA} in java code  its printing the all data inputted perfectly on Jenkins console but when when passed to maven its failing with below error

```
 String paramValue2= System.getProperty("DATA");
```

But when mvn command is run it fails with the below error, as maven is treating a new line as a new Goal and failing the same.I searched on many links but was not able to find the answer

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "52555#20-12-2023,2012-13-2023$". You
> must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format
> : or
> :[:]:.
> Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize,
> generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
> process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources,
> process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources,
> test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package,
> pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,
> install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site,
> post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

worked for me using the below command in Jenkins

```
 -DPACKAGE_DATA="${DATA}"
```